# PHP cannot enable module

Tags: openssl, php-ini, php, php-openssl

Currently we are trying to enable the openssl module in the PHP. We did the following:

1. Uncomment the `extension=php_openssl.dll` line in php.ini (the path to which is defined in the phpinfo page).
2. Restart the Apache server in the services window.

Upon checking the phpinfo page, the OpenSSL does not appear in the modules list so we assume that it is therefore not enabled.

Are there any other ways to enable it or am I overlooking some steps or issues that needs to be addressed?

Comment: are you using wamp? check into phpinfo for php.ini file location, is it correct file are you modifying?

Comment: firstly check the phpinfo to check where your php.ini  file exists in the installation then go to the php.ini and uncomment and restart the apache and check

Comment: You have to make sure that `libeay32.dll` is in the system path of Windows.

Comment: @Shaunak, I am using Appserv.

Comment: @NaveenThally, yes I've already made sure of that.

Comment: @Jack, that I have to check. Which component uses this dll?

Comment: What do you mean? `php_openssl.dll` uses `libeay32.dll` :)

Comment: @Jack not fully familiar with the dependencies so just checking :).

Comment: @Jack, `libeay32.dll` appears in C:\AppServ\Apache2.2\bin` which in turn appears in the PATH.

Comment: So are there still any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a UAC issue. While the issue persists in the remote machine that I am checking this issue does not exist in my machine. After several trial and error, I came across the "PHP Edit the php.ini Configuration File" menu in the Start Menu. Editing the php.ini file using this solves the problem.